# Is Haki based on anything real?

Tags: one-piece

In One Piece series, there's this 'will' technique called Haki. Is this based on anything real, all three of them?

Comment: http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Haki has some info on it but not much. It's under the trivia part

Comment: Anime is far from reality, imagine the disaster if such cases is for real. Perhaps, we human being only have natural instinct, and that is the reality.

Comment: I wouldn't say Haki is real but i think its the closest to severe and thorough Martial arts body condition training. We have seen people punch through several bricks, or Muay Thai fighters break an entire opponent's arm and part of the ribcage by just a kick... its body conditioning through vigorous training for years.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*I am not entirely sure about the credibility of this* but it does make sense and the only info I could find. Taken from the [wiki](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Haki) under Trivia and from this [answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/2783/1528)

> - Haki appears to be similar in principle to common types of **Qi** *(Chi)*
>     found in various other anime and manga series; which is based on the
>     concept of "qi" (or "life-force") in Chinese philosophy.
> - The concept of Kenbunshoku Haki, known to Skypieans as Mantra, is
>     loosely based on the style of thinking in Hinduism, which goes by the
>     same [name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mantra).

The original Japanese term is ki (pronounced the same as "key", written as 気). It can also be spelled chi or qi. The same term is used for a concept in martial arts.